# Ingest data from local with jupyter notebook into hdfs

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, hdfs

I'm trying to ingest data from local to hdfs ( hdfs and jupyter notebook are deployed into kubernetes)
:
[image]

[image]

I tired this command in jupyter but it doesn't work:

```
data.to_csv("hdfs:hdfs-namenode-0.hdfs-namenode.default.svc.cluster.data/NameOfFile")
```

i don't have an idea if i have to access into hdfs from jupyter notebook or not, i'm open to listen to your suggestion guys and thank you

Comment: is it `.svc.cluster.data` or it should be `.svc.cluster.local` ? what works for me is `df.write.csv("hdfs://hdfs-namenode-0.hdfs-namenode.default.svc.cluster.local/user/hdfs/test/findmeip.csv")
`

Comment: @HarshManvar i get always no such file or directory ""hdfs://hdfs-namenode-0.hdfs-namenode.default.svc.cluster.local/.."

Comment: what is your namespace name ? `hdfs-namenode` or `default` you have mentioned both. `<svc-name>.<namespacename>.svc.cluster.local` follow format like this

Comment: @HarshManvar my namespace is default, the name of the pod is hdfs-namenode-0 , the name of folder in the hdfs-namenode-0  is data

Comment: also i just noticed you are trying to connect to POD but using the service(svc) address. you can read more about the DNS here : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: if you are trying with POD use `pod-ip-address.namespace-name.pod.cluster.local` . get pod IP using `kubectl get pods -o wide` and try with appending path to it

Comment: @HarshManvar same error i got No such file or directory :

Comment: @HarshManvar i think the problem in the code , he can't access to the pod !

Comment: Could be possible thn